# With Flask and SQLite, access database out side of web app

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask app that is using sqlite.

I have a simple web app that will take in user info and store it into sqlite tables.

The issue that I am having is trying to access the sqlite database in other files that are part of the web app.

I am using the application factory flow in the [tutorial](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/tutorial/factory/)

When I try to access the database in another file, I get a context error.

```py
from flaskr.db import get_db

def get_data_from_db():
    db = get_db()

    user_from_db = db.execute(
        'SELECT name'
        ' FROM user '
    ).fetchall()

    return user_from_db
```

When I do this, it says that I am outside the context.

```
2021-07-07T22:28:20.111376+00:00 app[clock.1]:   File "/app/flaskr/alerts.py", line 25, in get_data_from_db
2021-07-07T22:28:20.111583+00:00 app[clock.1]:     db = get_db()
2021-07-07T22:28:20.111612+00:00 app[clock.1]:   File "/app/flaskr/db.py", line 9, in get_db
2021-07-07T22:28:20.111809+00:00 app[clock.1]:     if 'db' not in g:
2021-07-07T22:28:20.111839+00:00 app[clock.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 422, in __get__
2021-07-07T22:28:20.112208+00:00 app[clock.1]:     obj = instance._get_current_object()
2021-07-07T22:28:20.112236+00:00 app[clock.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 544, in _get_current_object
2021-07-07T22:28:20.112638+00:00 app[clock.1]:     return self.__local()  # type: ignore
2021-07-07T22:28:20.112666+00:00 app[clock.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/globals.py", line 40, in _lookup_app_object
2021-07-07T22:28:20.112866+00:00 app[clock.1]:     raise RuntimeError(_app_ctx_err_msg)
2021-07-07T22:28:20.112936+00:00 app[clock.1]: RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.
```

How do I get this to be in context so that I can access the db?

here is the repo and the branch I am working on.
https://github.com/besteman/futurama-mining/tree/first-pass-web-app
Basically, I want to have this file with the DB connection:
https://github.com/besteman/futurama-mining/blob/first-pass-web-app/flaskr/alerts.py#L26-L36

Comment: You need to import your app and use `with app.app_context: db = get_db()`

Comment: How would I import the app? when using the application factory approach?

Comment: I don't know how you have organized your directory if you paste the image of structure and explain in which file you are defining app. Then I could help, BTW you can also push it to github and paste the link here. So that I can help.

Comment: @charchit https://github.com/besteman/futurama-mining/tree/first-pass-web-app
here is the repo and the branch I am working on. 
Basically, I want to have this file with the DB connection:
https://github.com/besteman/futurama-mining/blob/first-pass-web-app/flaskr/alerts.py#L26-L36

Comment: Can you join this [repl](https://replit.com/join/ljeamgknsh-charchit123) or dm me on discord `charchit#8198` because I don't know about docker and how you are running app. I ran the app but and the app is running fine i can't login because i don't know password and there is no signup form

Comment: I started the website I don't see any errors in signing , making entries and editing them. I think website is running fine. Where is the error occurring ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an extensions.py file and add it there, and init_app in the create_app function:

`extensions.py`:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()
# other extensions, ( if you have )
```

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from extensions import db
from blueprints.example_blueprint_ import example_blueprint
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    db.init_app(app)
    # you can do any blueprint registration if any:
    # app.register_blueprint(example_blueprint)
    return app
app = create_app()
app.app_context().push()
from db_models import whatever_db_models
db.create_all()
```

`blueprints/example_blueprint_.py`:

```
from flask import Blueprint
from extensions import db
from db_models import model
example_blueprint = Blueprint(__name__)
@example_blueprint.route("/example")
def test():
    # An Example
    db.session.query(model).filter(condition).update({field_to_update: value_to_be_updated})
```

So your file structure could be like this:

```
- app.py
- extensions.py
- db_models.py
- blueprints
     - example_blueprint_.py
```

You don't need that function, get_from_db